# Coupon collector problem convergence

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

For  a  positive  integer $n$, there  are $n$ different coupons, and you are trying to collect them all.  Each time you purchase an item, you receive one of the $n$ coupons uniformly at random.  Let $T_n$ denote the amount of time it takes to collect all $n$ coupons. Prove that $\dfrac{T_n}{n\ln{n}} \to 1$ in probability as $n \to \infty$.
How do I approach this? I am thinking about using Chebyshev's inequality.